# Using pytorch cuda for RNNs on google colaboratory

Tags: neural-network, gpu, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

I have a code (a code we saw in a class) of a recurrent neural network that reads a given text and tries to produce its own text similar to the example. The code is written in python and uses the pytorch library. I wanted to modify to see whether I could increase its speed by using GPU instead of CPU and I made some tests on google collaboratory. The GPU version of the code runs fine but is about three times slower than the CPU version. I do not know the details of GPU architecture so I can not really understand why it is slower. I know that GPUs can do more arithmetic operations per cycle but have more limited memory so I am curious if I am having a memory issue. I also tried using CUDA with a generative adversarial network and in this case it was almost ten times faster. Any tips on this would be welcome.

The code (CUDA version) is below. I am new at this stuff so sorry if some of the terminology is not correct.
The architecture is input->encoder->recursive network->decoder->output.

```python
import torch
import time
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files

#uploding text on google collab
uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))


#data preprocessing

with open('text.txt','r') as file:
#with open closes the file after we are done with it
    rawtxt=file.read()

rawtxt = rawtxt.lower()

#a function that assigns a number to each unique character in the text
def create_map(rawtxt):
    letters = list(set(rawtxt))
    lettermap = dict(enumerate(letters)) #gives each letter in the list a number
    return lettermap


num_to_let = create_map(rawtxt)
#inverse to num_to_let
let_to_num =dict(zip(num_to_let.values(), num_to_let.keys()))


print(num_to_let)

#turns a text of characters into text of numbers using the mapping 
#given by the input mapdict
def maparray(txt, mapdict):

    txt = list(txt)

    for k, letter in enumerate(txt):
        txt[k]=mapdict[letter]

    txt=np.array(txt)
    return txt


X=maparray(rawtxt, let_to_num) #the data text in numeric format
Y= np.roll(X, -1, axis=0) #shifted data text in numeric format


X=torch.LongTensor(X)
Y=torch.LongTensor(Y)

#up to here we are done with data preprocessing


#return a random batch for training
#this reads a random piece inside data text
#with the size chunk_size
def random_chunk(chunk_size):
    k=np.random.randint(0,len(X)-chunk_size)
    return X[k:k+chunk_size], Y[k:k+chunk_size] 


nchars = len(num_to_let)


#define the recursive neural network class
class rnn(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,output_size, n_layers=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.n_layers= n_layers

        self.encoder = torch.nn.Embedding (input_size, hidden_size)
        self.rnn =  torch.nn.RNN(hidden_size, hidden_size, n_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.decoder = torch.nn.Linear (hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward (self,x,hidden):
        x=self.encoder(x.view(1,-1))

        output, hidden = self.rnn(x.view(1,1,-1), hidden)
        output = self.decoder(output.view(1,-1))

        return output, hidden

    def init_hidden(self):
        return Variable(torch.zeros(self.n_layers , 1 , self.hidden_size)).cuda()

#hyper-params
lr = 0.009
no_epochs = 50
chunk_size = 150

myrnn = rnn(nchars, 150, nchars,1)
myrnn.cuda()

criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(myrnn.parameters(), lr=lr)


t0 = time.time()

for epoch in range(no_epochs):
    totcost=0
    generated = ''

    for _ in range(len(X)//chunk_size):
        h=myrnn.init_hidden()   
        cost = 0
        x, y=random_chunk(chunk_size)
        x, y= Variable(x).cuda(), Variable(y).cuda()

        for i in range(chunk_size):
            out, h = myrnn.forward(x[i],h)

            _, outl = out.data.max(1)
            letter = num_to_let[outl[0]]
            generated+=letter

            cost += criterion(out, y[i])

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        cost.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        totcost+=cost
        totcost/=len(X)//chunk_size

    print('Epoch', epoch, 'Avg cost/chunk: ', totcost)
    print(generated[0:750],'\n\n\n')


t1 = time.time()    
total = t1-t0

print('total',total)

#we encode each word into a vector of fixed size
```